# receive http requests in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

API sends to my app message via http POST method.

To prevent data loss while my controller is off I want to use rabbit.

how to receive http POST requests in rabbitmq?

is possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There has to be some component which converts the requests. You also have to consider that the HTTP request requires a response. Do you respond with status 200/201 all the time, indicating "OK"/"Created"? What about errors you only discover later, when your controller is online again?

In your situation you might want to ask your users to send the data directly using RabbitMQ instead of using HTTP.

Comment: to send directly using Rabbitmq. can you clarify that please. External API sends me messages via post I cannot ask them to use rabbitmq.

Comment: Then you're f**cked, I'm afraid.

Comment: does it mean I cannot do anything to prevent data loss?